# DrawText issues

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32gui

I have a couple of issues with this function:

- The text turns into gibberish if I move the window a bit, or if I switch it to another monitor (Which has a different scaling, by the way)
- A smaller version of the text appears before the initial text if I make a call to CreateFont and SelectObject before printing the text

Am I doing it right? Maybe there's too many calls inside the WM_PAINT case? I'm not sure how else it could be done

My code:

```
case(WM_PAINT):
{
    HDC hDC = GetWindowDC(Window);

    RECT lpRect;
    GetClientRect(Window,
                  &lpRect
    );

    SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);

    DrawTextW(hDC,
              L"Loading...",
              -1,
              &lpRect,
              (DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP)
    );

    DeleteDC(hDC);
    break;
}
case(WM_ERASEBKGND):
{
    HDC hDC = GetWindowDC(Window);

    RECT lpRect;
    GetClientRect(Window, &lpRect); 

    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));

    FillRect(hDC, &lpRect, hBrush); 
    DeleteObject(hBrush);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I suggest you change `lpRect` to `rect`, as it is not a pointer to a `RECT` struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint), you must call [`BeginPaint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) and [`EndPaint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-endpaint). It's this way you obtain the device context. If you don't call `EndPaint()` the rect is not validated.

Comment: If you don't call `EndPaint` after a successful call to `BeginPaint`, your program is broken. But it's `BeginPaint` that validates the invalid region, not `EndPaint`.